# Circle with points on coordinate axis.

Tags: geometry, circles

If a circle has points $A$ and $B$ which lie on the coordinate axis and $AB$ is the diameter of the circle, would it always form a perfect circle where the midpoint of $AB$ is the centre of the circle?

The question states the line $y = -3x + 12$ meets the coordinate axis at $A$ and $B$. It asks you to find the equation of a circle that passes through points $A, B$and $O$ where $O$ is the origin.

The midpoint of $AB$ is $(2,6)$ so would this be the centre of the circle and if so, is it the same for all lines that meet the coordinate axis?

Comment: If you already start with a circle then what do you mean by "would it always form a circle.."?

Comment: The center of a circle is the middle of all diameters. Always.

Comment: What do you mean by a perfect circle?

Comment: @Anand: a "non-potato", maybe :-)

Comment: The line $y = -3x + 12$ meets each coordinate axis once. Is it possible that your question says that "the line y = -3x _ 12 meets the coordinate $\color{red}{axes}$ at $A$ and $B$? Note that in English, the word "axes" is the plural of "axis", and so you would know that $A$ lies on one coordinate axis, and $B$ lies on the other. This slight fix makes the problem actually sensible rather than utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\angle AOB=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, the circle must be centered at the midpoint of $AB$, which, as you say, would be the diameter of the circle. And the angle stays unchanged for random line intersecting both coordinate axis.